Significance vs Correlation in PCA using DEGreport (differential gene expression)?
I have done a differential expression analysis in EdgeR, including some biological and technical coefficients in the linear regression model.
Reading around online, principal component analysis seemed appropriate to investigate the contribution of these coefficients to the fit of the model. The DEGreport package has a function for doing PCA specifically on differential expression outputs called degCovariates.
The function calculates the principal components and the correlation of each coefficient to each component. What I'm confused about is for some coefficients there is a significant p value associated with certain PCs but the r value is NA?
Should I remove these coefficients from the model?

For advice about fitting statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. Or given the subject matter, maybe [bioinformatics.se].
